# AWS CloudFormation: Creating S3 bucket with credential outputs and CORS does not work

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I have the following AWS CloudFormation stack. The stack creates an S3 bucket, adds an IAM user and generates credentials for this user. The credentials are output in plain text once the stack is deployed (I understand the security implications of this).

Everything seems to work and the bucket is indeed created as expected. But when I test the resulting credentials, they work when using e.g. `TnTDrive` to access the S3 bucket - but not when using an S3 browser tool, [CANcloud](https://canlogger.csselectronics.com/cancloud/#/login), to login. This indicates that there is an issue with the CORS policy.

However, if I then generate a new set of credentials on the same IAM user 'manually' via the console, they work.

What am I doing wrong in this case?

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "CloudFormation template to create an S3 bucket, IAM users, and policies.",
    "Parameters": {
        "BucketName": {
            "Description": "The name of the S3 bucket",
            "Type": "String",
            "AllowedPattern": "^[a-z0-9.-]{3,63}$",
            "ConstraintDescription": "Bucket name can contain lowercase letters, numbers, hyphens, and periods. It must be between 3 and 63 characters."
        },
        "Region": {
            "Description": "AWS region where the bucket will be created",
            "Type": "String",
            "AllowedValues": [
                "us-east-1",
                "us-east-2",
                "us-west-1",
                "us-west-2",
                "af-south-1",
                "ap-east-1",
                "ap-south-2",
                "ap-southeast-3",
                "ap-southeast-4",
                "ap-south-1",
                "ap-northeast-3",
                "ap-northeast-2",
                "ap-southeast-1",
                "ap-southeast-2",
                "ap-northeast-1",
                "ca-central-1",
                "cn-north-1",
                "cn-northwest-1",
                "eu-central-1",
                "eu-west-1",
                "eu-west-2",
                "eu-south-1",
                "eu-west-3",
                "eu-north-1",
                "eu-south-2",
                "eu-central-2",
                "sa-east-1",
                "me-south-1",
                "me-central-1",
                "il-central-1",
                "us-gov-east-1",
                "us-gov-west-1"
            ],
            "Default": "us-east-1",
            "ConstraintDescription": "Must be a valid AWS region."
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "AmazonS3FullAccessBucketUser": {
            "DependsOn": "MyS3Bucket",
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::User"
        },
        "AmazonS3FullAccessBucketPolicy": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
            "Properties": {
                "PolicyName": "FullAccessToSpecificBucket",
                "Users": [
                    {
                        "Ref": "AmazonS3FullAccessBucketUser"
                    }
                ],
                "PolicyDocument": {
                    "Version": "2012-10-17",
                    "Statement": [
                        {
                            "Effect": "Allow",
                            "Action": [
                                "s3:*",
                                "s3-object-lambda:*"
                            ],
                            "Resource": [
                                {
                                    "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}"
                                },
                                {
                                    "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}/*"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "AmazonS3FullAccessBucketKeys": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::AccessKey",
            "Properties": {
                "UserName": {
                    "Ref": "AmazonS3FullAccessBucketUser"
                }
            }
        },
        "MyS3Bucket": {
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "Properties": {
                "BucketName": {
                    "Ref": "BucketName"
                },
                "CorsConfiguration": {
                    "CorsRules": [
                        {
                            "AllowedHeaders": [
                                "*"
                            ],
                            "AllowedMethods": [
                                "GET",
                                "PUT",
                                "POST",
                                "DELETE",
                                "HEAD"
                            ],
                            "AllowedOrigins": [
                                "*"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "FullAccessUserAccessKey": {
            "Description": "Access Key for IAM user with full S3 access",
            "Value": {
                "Ref": "AmazonS3FullAccessBucketKeys"
            }
        },
        "FullAccessUserSecretKey": {
            "Description": "Secret Key for IAM user with full S3 access",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "AmazonS3FullAccessBucketKeys",
                    "SecretAccessKey"
                ]
            }
        },
        "BucketEndpoint": {
            "Description": "Endpoint URL for the created S3 bucket",
            "Value": {
                "Fn::Sub": "http://s3.${Region}.amazonaws.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *But when I test the resulting credentials, they appear not to work* meaning what?

Comment: I tried your template and the output credentials seems to work: they connect correctly via CLI. How are you trying to use them?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've updated the question to clarify that the issue appears to be CORS related. It should be possible to replicate my issue by using the tool CANcloud (serving just as a browser method for logging in) together with the output S3 credentials/endpoint/bucket name. You'll be able to verify that you're unable to login, but once you create a new credential set, you can login

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that when copying the output S3 credentials from the CloudFormation outputs, there is an end space added to each field. In some tools, e.g. TntDrive, this causes no problems as the tool automatically trims end spaces. But in some tools, like CANcloud, end spaces are not trimmed - causing the problem. The reason this then did not appear as an issue via the manual IAM user creation was that no end spaces were added here of course.

So in conclusion, this was a simple error on my side, but not obvious from the CFT output as the end space does not appear on the fields when selecting.